# How to use current version in configurations in gradle

Tags: gradle

Situation: In my build.gradle file I have 2 separate configurations for pulling in specific dependencies.

One is called configJars where I pull down jars to unpack and get specific json files from.

My question is, is there a way to call out the versions that are already being resolved in the compile/transitive dependencies.
com.example:common:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT

I attempted to use "+" but this only pulls the latest version that is available in the repo which is not what I require.
configJars(group: "com.example", name: "common", version: "+")
+--- com.example:common:+ -> 3.2.18-SNAPSHOT

I need to use the version that is being used by a specific dependency that gets updated by a different team.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the library that was doing the update to my other libraries and removed the other libraries from the build file. SO they get pulled in transitively and explicitly exclude the libraries I don't need from the transitive pull.

I had to change the configuration to transitive = true and change all the dependency declarations to { transitive = false}.

A bit messy but it worked out.